# AMCharts Year on Year

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am trying to create a graph that displays the years data on top of each other. The data I have is as follows (Json Format with only 2 entries):

[{
"date":"2015-01-10",
"amount":51766
},
{
"date":"2016-01-10",
"amount":51766
}]

I want to display this on a serial chart but when I do all it does it show one year and then continues onto the next year. What I want to do is show a line (Lets say yellow line) for 2015 and another for 2016 (orange Line) with the months and days as the y axis and the amount as the x axis.

The following image describes what I mean:

[image]

Any help on how this would be done would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: have you attempted anything? Show us the code

Comment: I have uploaded my "static" version here http://codepen.io/andrewbeatson/pen/vKpRNp the reason i say static is because i went in and put each 2016 value next to the dates that had those values available but I know there must be a way to automatically sort that out?

Comment: No, there isn't a built-in functionality like this, I'm afraid. You can built some sort of automatic pre-processor of data, though.